# Can I call jQuery method with given selector, method name and variable arguments?

Tags: jquery, call, apply, dispatch

I tried to find the way through web search, but I could not.

What I want to do is dispatching jQuery method like below;

```
var dispatchFunction = function (selector, jQueryMethod, jQueryArgs) {
    jQuery(selector)[jQueryMethod].apply(this, jQueryArgs);
}
```

Although It looks like the result of

```
jQuery("#id")["methodName"]
```

is a function. But when I call 'apply' to that function in javascript console, it does not work like below;

```
func = jQuery("#todo")["text"];
=> function (e){return b.access(this,function(e){return e===t?b.text(this):this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||o).createTextNode(e))},null,e,arguments.length)}

jQuery("#todo")["text"]();
=> "abc"

func.apply(this);
=> ""

func.apply(this, []);
=> ""
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not sure I get this, can't you just do -> `$(variable1)[variable2](variable3);` ??

Comment: Why are you putting a function in a variable? Why anonymously?  Why not name the function and just call it like normal?

Comment: @Phillip Because my code needs to receive some method calls, and deal with them if it can, or it delegate them to jQuery. So I need to dispatch method dynamically to jQuery.

Comment: @adeneo I need to call jQuery method with variable arguments. So there can be multiple arguments like variable3, variable4, so on. That's why I tried to use 'apply'.

Comment: *Phillip* was probably talking about the function declaration using `var` - you could write `function dispatchFunction(...)`. But that has noting to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
var dispatchFunction = function (selector, jQueryMethod, jQueryArgs) {
    var selection = jQuery(selector);
    selection[jQueryMethod].apply(selection, jQueryArgs);
}
```

You might want to read more info about `this` keyword and function vs method calls in JS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer has solved my problem. I really appreciate you. :)